# Does white spruce have new growth only in spring?

Tags: growth, evergreens, spruces

In May my white spruce started growing new branches, and by now they are almost the same color as the rest of the tree. There are still some old branches that have really small buds, but no new growth.

Do spruces grow only in spring, or is there any chance that the tree will grow more during this summer and autumn? Is there any way to encourage growth?

Answer (score 2):

Conifers with needles put out new growth "candles" in spring and do not put on more new growth until the next year . The new candles can be pruned but if you prune a mature twig ,it will not grow the following year.   I don't know about Junipers , cedars. etc. Yews can be pruned anytime and will keep growing.